# Isothermal expasion of an elastic metal rod - how does the internal energy change with entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics

I've been playing around with some simple thermodynamics of elastic rods, but have ended up tying myself in knots. I wonder if anyone can help me sleep tonight by pointing out where I've gone wrong :-)

The first law of thermodynamics for the system can be written as $dU = TdS + fdL$, where $f$ is the tension applied to the rod and $dL$ the infinitesimal change in length. Therefore, to the best of my ability, it seems to follow that, in an isothermal and reversible change:

$$\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right)_T = \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial L} \right)_T \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial S} \right)_T = \left[ T \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial L} \right)_T + f \right]\left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial S} \right)_T = T+f\left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial S} \right)_T = T + \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial L} \right)_S\left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial S} \right)_T=T - \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right)_L$$

Since $\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right)_L = T$, then it seems to follow that
$\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right)_T = T - T = 0$

Is this correct?

If it is, I'm finding it hard to interpret this result physically. Isothermally extending an elastic metal rod increases its entropy, and does positive work on the rod. Therefore, the internal energy of the rod increases. Then how (on Earth) to interpret the result $\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right)_T = 0$ ?

Comment: Here is a reference on Hookean thermoelasticity that I have found very informative:  http://maeresearch.ucsd.edu/~vlubarda/research/pdfpapers/ijss-04.pdf

Comment: Thanks, Chet. I will read it carefully.

Comment: How are you replacing $\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial L} \right)_S\left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial S} \right)_T$ with $- \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right)_L$?

Comment: Chemomechanics, by wishful thinking it seems! :-) That's it, that's my blunder. Thanks very much for spotting it!

Comment: Happens to us all!